# Parsing lags in a time series

Tags: r, time-series

I'm making a table of lagged columns for time series data, but I'm having trouble reshaping the data.

My original data.table looks like this:

A data table sorted by descending years column and a doy column with one value, the n_a column starts from 9 and descends to 4

[image]

And I want to make it look like this:

Lagged variable time series table where each column starts with the row after the prev
[image]

Comment: Please provide your test data in reproducible text-based format. Anyone wishing to demonstrate a solution would have to transcribe from your image, whereas if you included the text `df <- data.frame(doy = 1, year = 2022:2017, n_a = 9:4)` in a code block, folks here could copy and paste it over to test and verify solutions. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your data frame is called `df`, you can do:

```r
df[4:7] <- lapply(1:4, function(x) dplyr::lead(df$n_a, x))
names(df)[4:7] <- paste0('n_a_lag', 1:4)

df
#>   doy year n_a n_a_lag1 n_a_lag2 n_a_lag3 n_a_lag4
#> 1   1 2022   9        8        7        6        5
#> 2   1 2021   8        7        6        5        4
#> 3   1 2020   7        6        5        4       NA
#> 4   1 2019   6        5        4       NA       NA
#> 5   1 2018   5        4       NA       NA       NA
#> 6   1 2017   4       NA       NA       NA       NA
```

---

**Data taken from image in question, in reproducible format**

```r
df <- data.frame(doy = 1, year = 2022:2017, n_a = 9:4)

df
#>   doy year n_a
#> 1   1 2022   9
#> 2   1 2021   8
#> 3   1 2020   7
#> 4   1 2019   6
#> 5   1 2018   5
#> 6   1 2017   4
```

<sup>Created on 2022-07-21 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

You can use `data.table::shift` for a multiple leads and lags:

```
d[,(paste0("n_a_lag",1:4)):= shift(n_a,1:4,type = "lead")]
```

Output:

```
     doy  year   n_a n_a_lag1 n_a_lag2 n_a_lag3 n_a_lag4
   <num> <int> <int>    <int>    <int>    <int>    <int>
1:     1  2022     9        8        7        6        5
2:     1  2021     8        7        6        5        4
3:     1  2020     7        6        5        4       NA
4:     1  2019     6        5        4       NA       NA
5:     1  2018     5        4       NA       NA       NA
6:     1  2017     4       NA       NA       NA       NA
```

Input:

```
d = data.table(
  doy =c(1,1,1,1,1,1),
  year = 2022:2017,
  n_a=9:4
)
```

Comment: a  more appropriate name for each of these columns might be `"n_a_lead<x>"`, but I've matched the OP's terminology (which many would considered reversed from the usual vernacular)

Comment: Thanks langtang! I confused lead and lag, appreciate your support